# Particles.js - How to make a character as particles

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

Hi actually i want to make the specific text to particles. I mean i want it like in the image(dropbox.com/s/y43jf4vzdr5cd9p/p.png?dl=0) for example if i give P, This P should transform like in the image. Is it possible?. In order to achieve that i used particle.js JavaScript file. I tried a lot to finish myself but i couldn't achieve. Further i have no idea to achieve this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```js
/* ---- particles.js config ---- */

particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 380,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});


/* ---- stats.js config ---- */

var count_particles, stats, update;
stats = new Stats;
stats.setMode(0);
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
count_particles = document.querySelector('.js-count-particles');
update = function() {
  stats.begin();
  stats.end();
  if (window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles && window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array) {
    count_particles.innerText = window.pJSDom[0].pJS.particles.array.length;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #b61924;
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>

<!-- particles.js container -->
<div id="particles-js"></div>
```

*emphasized text*

Comment: Any one help me to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this file particles.min.js. You'll search inside the normal file (particles.js) this word "circle". For me, i had two results (lucky), when you are into the switch under the "circle" case, you just add these lines:

```
case "circle":
    var context = pJS.canvas.ctx.canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillText("Hello World!", p.x, p.y);
    context.fill();
    break;
```

And enjoy! Then you can do everything.

Comment: I changed the case but nothing works. Please see the example(https://codepen.io/pkprabu/pen/OdyrpY) Can you provide a working example, Please?

Comment: You go to the official site (https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/), then open the inspector -> tab source -> crtl+p and write "particles.js" -> inside the file search "circle" when you found the case (it stay above) copy and paste the follow code lines. if you dont understand, write me.

Comment: this is my example, do you like?

Comment: Thank you :) But actually i want it like in the image(https://www.dropbox.com/s/y43jf4vzdr5cd9p/p.png?dl=0) for example if i give  P, This P should transform like in the image. Is it possible?

Comment: aaaaah i am understanding now. It's much more complex. :P